# Load average is have been high over some period

Tags: mysql, centos

We have a dedicated MySQL server and below is the a snapshot of the top. The load average has been staying at nearly 100 for an hour plus ready.

```
top - 20:54:28 up  7:31,  2 users,  load average: 83.08, 96.88, 106.23
Tasks: 278 total,   2 running, 274 sleeping,   2 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu0  : 18.8%us, 10.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 70.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  : 51.2%us,  4.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 44.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :  9.0%us, 10.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 80.6%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  : 18.8%us,  7.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 73.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu4  :  7.8%us,  8.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 83.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu5  : 10.3%us,  8.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 81.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu6  :  6.2%us,  7.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu7  :  6.2%us,  6.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 87.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Cpu8  :  8.8%us, 10.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 80.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Cpu9  : 63.7%us,  4.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 12.2%id,  0.0%wa,  4.3%hi, 15.2%si,  0.0%st
Cpu10 :  9.2%us, 10.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 80.6%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu11 : 17.3%us,  5.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 76.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu12 :  8.0%us,  8.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 83.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu13 : 10.9%us,  7.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 81.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu14 :  6.2%us,  6.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu15 :  4.8%us,  6.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 89.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st

Mem:  33009800k total, 23174396k used,  9835404k free,   120604k buffers
Swap: 35061752k total,        0k used, 35061752k free, 16459540k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 3341 mysql     20   0 14.3g 4.6g 4240 S 417.8 14.5   1673:51 mysqld
24406 root      20   0 15008 1292  876 R  0.3  0.0   0:00.19 top
    1 root      20   0  4080  852  608 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.92 init
    2 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.32 migration/0
    4 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.29 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0
    6 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.21 migration/1
    7 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.07 ksoftirqd/1
    8 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/1
    9 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.17 migration/2
   10 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 ksoftirqd/2
   11 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/2
   12 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.32 migration/3
   13 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/3
   14 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/3
   15 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.10 migration/4
   16 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.04 ksoftirqd/4
   17 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/4
   18 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.35 migration/5
```

We have also tried to run this command. What else command can help us diagnose the exact problem of this high load?

```
netstat -nat |grep 3306 | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 LISTEN
      1 SYN_RECV
    410 ESTABLISHED
    964 TIME_WAIT
```

Output of `vmstat 1`:

```
---------------memory--------------- --swap-- --io-- --system-- -----cpu------
 r b swpd  free     buff    cache    si so    bi  bo in  cs     us sy id wa st
 2 0 0     12978936 30944   15172360 0  0     259 3  184 265    6  6  77 12 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some things to get you started.   Try these in order:

1. Run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` in MySQL.  Look for the queries that have been running the longest.
2. Turn the MySQL slow log on, set the `long_query_time` to an appropriate value and use either `mysqldumpslow -s at <logfile>` or `mysqldumpslow -s t <logile>`.  (Replace `<logfile>` with the path to your logfile.)
3. Turn `log_queries_not_using_indexes` on and repeat the above `mysqldumpslow -s t` command.  Since your problem is CPU, this is less likely to be the root cause, but it could be if you are seeing a lot of simple queries or a few very complex queries over a small table.  **Beware:** Depending on your indexes, this logging option can cause a lot of writes to the disk which can cause your load average to climb even higher.
4. Get some monitoring going using [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) or [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) and the [Better Cacti Templates for MySQL](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cacti-templates/)(now called the Percona Monitoring Project) or the [Zabbix Appaloosa Templates for MySQL](http://code.google.com/p/appaloosa-zabbix-templates/).  Since you won't have any idea of what the graphs looked like **before** the problem started, this won't be quite as useful as it could have been if you had installed it right from the start.

It sounds like this is related to [your older question](https://serverfault.com/questions/373144/mysql-showing-some-high-spikes).  Have you tried what was suggested there?  How did it go?

Comment: what I am curious is why is the cpu percentage is quite low but the load is still heavy is it that my cpus are not working to the max any reason for it? I did not have time to install the cacti quite a waste cause i was concentrating on the index. Could this be a hardware problem?

Comment: Low CPU with high load average is usually caused by high disk utlisation (this is how much the processes want to read from and write to the disks, not how much is stored on them).  This can be found with `vmstat 1`.  `vmstat` shows raw numbers and doesn't show any history from before the problem but the `wa` column shows how much the CPUs are waiting on disk access.  If that's high, disk access is a problem for you.

Comment: from the top which I put can we say that the cpu usage is low or high? Here is one of the vmstat  vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 2  0      0 12978936  30944 15172360    0    0   259     3  184  265  6  6 77 12  0

Comment: You have 32GB of RAM, 22GB of it is in use and MySQL is only using 4.6GB.  What else is running on this box?  And have you tried using mysqltuner.pl to tune your MySQL?  It may be a lot happier with more of the RAM.  Which config parameters you change depend on what engine you are using.

Comment: do you think the wa is high not quite soo right? I have not tried mysqltuner.pl u need perl for that right? Nothing else is running on this box except for mysql. So how to know what is eating up the ram then?

Comment: top only show mysql the highest user the rest are all 0.0? Is there any hidden process which escapes from the top?

Comment: Yes, you need perl to use mysqltuner.pl.  You can sort `top` by memory usage by typing `O q <return>` for resident size or `O n <return>` for memory percentage.

Comment: I tried bot your option surprisingly it just showed me both also only mysql the rest is like 0.0 what could be wrong ya?

Comment: If I may chip in, if memory usage for mysql is low, check your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` setting. It could be that you're not utilizing all your memory as effectively as you could be

Comment: @sreimer ok will do that but in the server most are just myisam file no innodb yet

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a massive slow queries somewhere in your bases. Try to turn "ON" slow_query_log for mysqld and look what happens. 
May be some index is broken. Try to check/analyze tables.

Comment: @kondbas yes there is some  slow queries. but those queries I are scanning through few thousand lines too. Secondly how to check/analyse table?

Comment: Slow queries are those that haven't appropriate indices or use indices that broken. In that cases query begins to "filesort" that means slow plainsearch in tables instead of fast search by some kind of tree structure. That also may happens when your query is bad designed - read Mysql manual chapter 7 for hints about query optimization.

Comment: query `CHECK TABLE some_table;` shows you status of table. If something goes wrong you'll get a message that REPAIR needed.

Comment: there is one which I suspected so now I am repairing why it keeping getting problem is it due to its big size is it? but what is eating up my memory cause mysql if you see is just taking up 4.6 gb out of the 32Gb memory?

Answer (score 0):

install and use mtop, it's a top like program that show queries instead of processes and it will give you a realtime insight about what queries are runinnig and those who are blocking the server.
then you may use mysqltuner script available at mysqltuner.com to run a diagnostic on your server and see if there are some params to tune

Comment: @montassar ok I will try to install I tried yum install mtop but it does tell me no package to install either.

Comment: mtop is not available via package managers, you need to install it from sources, it's quite simple and should run straight forward without problem if you follow instruction in the README file

Comment: @montassar Far more useful tools are `Mysql Workbench` and `HeidiSQL`. I prefer HeidiSQL inspite it is win-app, it works quite well in wine.

Comment: @kondybas indeed / you just need to mention not to install wine on a production server running MySQL :)

Comment: I would use innotop instead of mtop. You don't even need to install it; it's a single file you can just execute.

Comment: @montassar Workbench/HeidiSQL both suited for remote administration via tcp/ssl

Comment: @all how different is this heidisql and workbench from phpMyAdmin then because I saw most of the features are there in phpMyAdmin too right?